# jsf 2.0 property not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish-4

I am looking for a problem since 2 days now and i can´t solve it!
My jsf managed bean looks like that:

```
@Named(value = "hardwareRevisionCreateController")
@RequestScoped
public class HardwareRevisionCreateController {

    private Hardware.Type type;

    public HardwareRevisionCreateController() {
    }

    public Hardware.Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Hardware.Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Hardware.Type> getHardwareTypes() {
        List<Hardware.Type> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(Hardware.Type.values()));
        return list;
    }
}
```

and i want to access the variable hardwareTypes from my jsf page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{hardwareRevisionCreateController.type}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{hardwareRevisionCreateController.hardwareTypes}"
                    var="type"
                    itemValue="#{type}"
                    itemLabel="#{type.name()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and i get the following error:

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.thomasperoutka.alptiming.controller.HardwareRevisionCreateController' does not have the property 'hardwareTypes'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:208)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:847)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:297)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Anyone an idea of the problem?

Comment: Strange behaviour. Just out of curiosity: set a debug breakpoint into the constructor (check if the controller actually gets instantiated) and also into the getHardwareTypes-method. Also, does the behaviour change when you return an array instead of a list? Hope it helps...

Comment: yes i added a breakpoint in the constructor and all of a sudden it worked! very strange behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

As I recall you have to declare a variable with that name, just getter isn't enough. Try adding `private List<Hardware.Type> hardwareTypes;` to the bean. And change getter to

```
public List<Hardware.Type> getHardwareTypes() {
    if (this.hardwareTypes == null) {
        hardwareTypes = new ArrayList<Hardware.Type>();
        hardwareTypes.addAll(Arrays.asList(Hardware.Type.values()));
    }
    return this.hardwareTypes;
}
```

Or (never tried this) try simply changing the value to `value="#{hardwareRevisionCreateController.getHardwareTypes()}"`

Comment: i tried both methodes but i always get the same error. when i try the second method i get "Method getHardwareTypes not found".

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it but i still have no idea why this error was happening.
I now changed the jsf code to

```
value="#{hardwareRevisionCreateController.getHardwareTypes()}"
```

but after that it was still not working. I added an breakpoint to the constructor and all of a sudden it worked (later on also without the breakpoint).
Maybe a problem with caching? (I have tried several times the clean and build button).
I was using the newest NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
Maybe i could help someone.

Comment: when you call getHardwareTypes it means that you refenrence hardwareTypes properties, but when you call hardwareTypes()-it means you reference method